# Melhoria de código javascript para validação de campo site

Tags: javascript, formulário, validação

Bom dia galera, preciso apenas de uma ajuda em melhoria de uma validação de campo por javascript.
No meu formulário existe um campo chamado website e preciso que tenha uma validação de url (já fiz) e preciso que haja um bloqueio de algumas palavras não permitida nesse mesmo campo. Por exemplo: Google, Facebook, etc.

O meu código está assim:

```
function validateForm() {
    var url = document.forms["registration"]["website"].value;

    var pattern =  /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;

    var re =  /facebook|Facebook|Google|google|linkedin|youtube|semsite|não|nosite|naotem|naotenho|asd|kkk|qqq|fff|aaa|ccc|ppp|haha|hehe/;

    var result = url.match(re);
    if (result == "facebook") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "Facebook") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "google") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "Google") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "linkedin") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "linkedin") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "youtube") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "semsite") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "não") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "nosite") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "naotem") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "naotenho") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "asd") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "kkk") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "qqq") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "fff") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "aaa") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "ccc") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "ppp") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "haha") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }
    if (result == "hehe") {
        alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
        return false;
    }

    if (pattern.test(url)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("A URL não é valida");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Mas note que isso não é uma prática tão correta de se fazer, pois toda vez que precisar adicionar uma nova palavra precisarei criar ali mais uma validação. Alguém teria uma sugestão para ajudar a melhora-lo?

Obrigado.

Comment: todas as mensagens são iguais, por que usar tantos `if`? não poderia usar um único if como `if(result != undefined && result != '')`?

Comment: Essa é minha ideia, tirar esses tanto de if e buscar uma solução simples para que sempre que precisar colocar uma nova palavra não precisar colocar mais if entende. Vou tentar dessa forma que você disse. @RicardoPontual

Comment: @RicardoPontual da forma que passou não funciona. Não está bloqueando a palavra que preciso.

Comment: pode testar mudando o if para `if(result != null)`?

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro você usar a função indexOf para verificar todas essas palavras.

```js
var forbidden = ['banana', 'maca', 'pera'];

var result = 'banana';

document.write(forbidden.indexOf(result)>-1?'Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site':'Not big deal');
```

Answer (score 0):

Nessa linha de código: var result = url.match(re); a variável result só será preenchida se encontrar valores correspondentes na variável url, logo meu teste seria:

```js
var result = url.match(re);
if (result != null) {
    alert("Essa palavra não é permitida no campo site");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```